# How can I mount a CephFS volume on CoreOS using my monitors' domain name?

Tags: coreos, ceph

I am trying to mount a CephFS volume on CoreOS. It currently works by specifying the IP address of one of my monitors:

`mount -t ceph 1.2.3.4:6789:/ /mnt`

However, I have three monitors for redundancy and have configured my DNS server to resolve to all three of them so I want to specify the domain name instead of the IPs:

`mount -t ceph ceph-mon:6789:/ /mnt`

However, this doesn't work. I think mount relies on mount.ceph being installed properly in order to resolve hostnames but I'm not certain about that.

How can I achieve this with CoreOS?